# Помогите. Service на Android без UI

Tags: java, android

Код:
MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба создана", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба остановлена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        >
        <service android:name=".MyService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        </service>
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                    tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

BootReceiver.java

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT COMPLETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECTIVITY_ACTION COMPLETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "OR NOTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

Вроде все правильно, получается что регистрируется служба, потом выполняется BootReceiver при включении телефона, потом context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class)) запускается служба... но я ничего не вижу, нет ни оповещений, ничего... что может быть не так?

Comment: Может кто нибудь протестировать у себя, работает ли данный код????

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `логи` вместо `Toast`:

```
private static final String TAG = "myApp";

Log.d(TAG, "моё сообщение");
```

Comment: он высвечивает что не может запустить службу после установки, я устанавливал ее на телефон и правда, кнопка запустить не активна, но после перезапуска служба находится в активных, но опять же ничего не происходит.

Comment: Не понял о чём вы...